# "Contact us"... and then what?

Tags: support, account-suspension, time, contact

So I had a dispute with the moderators at a specific SE site. As a result, I got suspended there. As per SE guidelines, I pressed the "Contact us" button and wrote to the higher powers to appeal.

That was *5-6 weeks* ago. There was zero feedback, neither positive, nor negative, not even "it's in progress, please wait".

So what is this "contact us" thing supposed to do? Is it a placebo to make me feel better while being routed to dev/null?

### What is the normal time it takes to process a "contact us" message?

Notes:

- As far as I remember, I did not contact the team before. I'm a longtime user of multiple SE sites and never had any problems except for that one site.
- I'm pretty sure my form was submitted. I didn't make screenshots or anything, because I did not think I would need them in a post like this. I didn't expect a super-fast reply either, so I wasn't wondering after a week or two.

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks .... so you're just about to enter the slot you might get an answer ....

Comment: Did you contact the team before?

Comment: @ShadowWizard As far as I remember, no. I'm a longtime user of multiple SE sites and never had any problems except for that one site.

Comment: And you sure your form was submitted? No errors? e.g. maybe you put wrong profile URL, missed the error, thought it was sent, and closed the tab.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I'm pretty sure. I didn't make screenshots or anything, I did not think I would need them in a post like this. I didn't expect a super-fast reply either, so I wasn't wondering after a week or two.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To begin with - sorry for the delay in response to your ticket. Regardless of my formal and informal explanation of the scenario below, a sorry is warranted here. We'll look into getting a response to your specific case handled.

---

Typically, it doesn't take that long to get a response from Contact Us. A subset of the Community Growth Ops team, the duo of JNat and animuson, is responsible for running through tickets when they come in. Holidays or other elements might interfere with the process temporarily but the vast majority of tickets get handled swiftly. Sometimes, such as appealing (or even simply just discussing) a suspension, it'll require one of the other Community Growth team members to step in, do deep research and potentially reaching out to the moderators in question as well, before composing the response. Typically this shouldn't take much more than the time it takes to grab someone - they might be in the middle of a task but **they usually round it up in tasks to handle by the end of day or at least end of week**.

If a longer amount of time is expected, then usually the assigned individual will send a ticket saying something along the lines of "We are looking into this but it may take a while." But if it *isn't* expected to take a long amount of time, then this kind of formality might end up passed over. Which is usually fine since that means it usually gets responded to quickly enough to not need it... but...

Workloads fluctuate. Between championing some of our other services (Docs, Dev Story, etc.), or handling recurring/important tasks (Area 51, elections, DMCA, etc.), there's a lot of times when one of us... bites off more than they can chew. They grab something which looks like it'll only take a quick bit in the afternoon but get ambushed with a other piles of work that makes the original task fade out of mind for... too long.

Basically this is a pretty longwinded way of saying "Normally it doesn't take that long but [oops someone made a goof](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348845/will-there-be-open-source-advertising-in-2017/349016#349016)."

Comment: You can send a "Thank you, we got your request" email. It's really simple, and... well, trivial. (Not you personally, it can be automated)

Comment: When you reach out through Contact Us, [you receive the following confirmation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJoho.png). Sending a followup email that just echoes that seems redundant and not particularly any more convincing. As it notes, though, a proper response *usually* would come "shortly", and as I note, if the person *expects* it to take longer, we usually would send an intervening message just to give word. The times it falls through are those rare situations where it's not expected to take long, but it ends up taking long.

Comment: Is this still up to date? Considered to close [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394896/how-do-i-track-the-status-of-a-ticket-i-lodged-over-the-contact-form) as dupe, but not sure if what's written here is still relevant.