# Is Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow staff really interested in users' feedback?

Tags: support, moderators, feedback, contact

After some years of enthusiasm about Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites, admiring the politeness of the communities and the effectiveness of the whole system, I finally stumbled upon a serious problem, and decided to make a complaint to the staff.

In this page [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges),
I've read about what to do in that case, of course after having made the other recommended actions.

I wrote a message using the "Contact" link "at the bottom of any page", as stated. Two months have passed, and still nothing is happened, not even a signal that someone did read my complaint.

I then searched for some other way, and found this page: [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do)
where there is a list of people that should "help you out, really". In their profile page you can find their email addresses. I wrote an email to three of them, leaving some day between each one. Again, no replies, no signals that someone has even received my messages.

Now I wonder: are these people really interested in user's feedback, or at least interested in ensuring that no abuses or other serious problems grow in their communities? This is question 1.

Question 2: Are those email addresses fake or what? Are they supplied just to give the impression that someone cares about users?

Question 3: What can I do now? Should I sit in peace and leave? Or is there still something I can try, once again?

--- update ---

It has been suggested that this question: ["Contact us"... and then what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296310/contact-us-and-then-what) could be the right answer. I think no, because it is 3 years old and it does not suggest what to do other than wait for a week. I've read that there are, these days, new efforts in improving exactly these kinds of problems. I am referring, for example, at the tag "status-review".

Moreover, I want to understand better what the Community Team does ([Who is on the Community Management Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do)): I wrote an email to some of them, but nobody replied. Wouldn't it better, at least, to inform the user with something like "we received your email but we have no time to examine it: please be patient"? Now I have the doubt that the mail system does not work, but it seems more probable that the CM really does not reply.

Comment: The CM team is very-very short of resources. Extremely short. So, I am not surprised to learn that it takes a long time. Now, I just want to confirm that you tried to create a meta-discussion for this action/situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Contact us"... and then what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296310/contact-us-and-then-what)  If I ever had cause to use that button and had not received an acknowledgement of my submission after two months then what I would do is to make a second submission stating the date on which the first was made, and including the content of the first submission.

Comment: @PolyGeo thank you for the link; unfortunately that Q+A is three years old, and says that the staff usually replies in about a week. I believe that now things can be different, as Anton said.

Comment: Did you send it from this account? Because... uh... I got two emails this week and neither was from your email address or account name.

Comment: Yes, @Catija, I've sent an email to you, from this account. I resend it now. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: "*Do they are published just to give...*" is not grammatical. I might have edited myself  but I've noticed you rollback entire edits, even the good bits. I'd suggest *Are they supplied just to give...*

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Unfortunately, I have experienced the same problem that you describe above several times in the last few months...

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you, I corrected and... I didn't want to rollback anything, actually it was a misclick but I thought nothing happened (probably it did instead); this evening I will inspect better.

Comment: @Nico thank you for your comment. At least I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Catija Last week I sent you an email too regarding a similar issue. Did you get it?