# What can I do if my support tickets are not being reviewed?

Tags: support, contact

I made a ticket about an issue 18 days ago and I have not received any help or messages. What can I do about this? Is this normal? Why do they take so long to review the ticket? Are they even going to review it?

If the staff needs more time because it is a "complex" issue (which I don't believe it is) why not send a short message, just to let the user know about the current situation? It feels like there is no care towards users from their point.

Comment: I'm not aware of any service level agreements so yes, they can take whatever time they want to review a ticket.

Comment: @rene I contacted the SO support team at the start of last year and they got to me fast. It took them about 1 day.

I improve SO site as many other developers, almost on daily basis. I think we deserve a good and fast support service. It makes me sad to feel left out in this regard.

Comment: Related: ["Contact us"... and then what?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296310/295232)

Comment: @Gass it really depends on what you contacted them for. As a moderator, if I e.g. send a ticket for a suicidal or underage user, it's usually obvious and handled quickly (there's a certain urgency to those too). If I am struggling with a large (but unobvious) sockpuppet ring, or a very unusual problem, it may take them quite a while to get back me. 18 days isn't too bad (yet).

Comment: To add to what @Tinkeringbell said, the response time depends on whether the Support team (the frontline responders to support tickets) can easily action the request, or if it needs to be forwarded to another team (e.g. the Community team, the developer team, etc.). Things like account merge requests, underage users, etc. can be actioned by the Support team quickly. On the other hand, other teams take quite a while to get back. When you send a ticket, you can rest assured that the Support team has read it and forwarded it as necessary, and there's nothing they can do at that point.

Comment: The 1-day response ticket above was likely easily actionable by the Support team, while the long-wait one you're talking about in your question probably had to be forwarded to another team.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The issue of my ticket isn't complex, it could be solved fast because I understood what the problem was. I by mistake double answered a question on two posts and a moderator thought I was copy pasting an existing answer. I deleted the question and explained everything on the ticket. My past issue was more complex than this one.

Comment: @Gass in this situation, you are supposed to raise a flag (on a question where it happened) for a moderator and briefly but clearly explain the situation. I don't see how raising a support ticket with the company can benefit you (especially, if you want things to happen sooner rather than later).

Comment: Wait... that's *it*? Question about support times aside, this is really something that ahould be resolved on the appropriate level - which is custom flagging with the same explanation - it's really not a matter where one needs to invole the company.

Comment: @AntonMenshov well.. But that is what I did.. And the moderator declined the flag.. It says "  a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it "..  What can you do in that case?? I have my arms tied

Comment: @Gass the next step could be a Meta discussion on Meta Stack Overflow (not this one). In which I would suggest focusing on the issue, and not on the moderator action (unless that is what you want to discuss).

Comment: That very much seems like a matter for the Community team, as they're the ones charged with handling such cases (site-specific matters where a moderator took an incorrect action), not for the Support team, which explains the high response time (they have a large backlog).

Comment: @AntonMenshov Oh I think I got confused between this site and the one you mention. Is all a little bit confusing. Thanks. I think the question can be closed now.

Comment: @Sonic As of ~November the support team no longer handles the Public Q&A queue, and it's handled by the community team directly (they forward stuff to us that isn't theirs instead). I haven't touched a community ticket in a while, myself. But I can say they have been very backlogged through much of January and even had a custom "response times may be longer" message going out for a while.

Answer (score 4):

I think the comments tell most of the story.

From OP's comments

> Thanks for all the comments. The issue of my ticket isn't complex, it could be solved fast because I understood what the problem was. I by mistake double answered a question on two posts and a moderator thought I was copy pasting an existing answer. I deleted the question and explained everything on the ticket. My past issue was more complex than this one.

This is 'relatively' trivial - if there's a bunch of *identical* answers from the same user we get a notification, and we do take plagiarism seriously if its identical to the answer from a different user. You get a notification, if there was a misunderstanding, you clear it up, and you move on.

This is also something generally handled by the mods on a site, and not *really* something that in my opinion "needs" CM escalation.

> @AntonMenshov well.. But that is what I did.. And the moderator declined the flag.. It says " a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it ".. What can you do in that case?? I have my arms tied

Mod actions generally deal with immediate issues. There's nothing 'really' to do. A mod reviewed the action and decided they didn't really need to do anything else. I'd suggest that you know what the problem is, and there was a misunderstanding, to, well try to do better in future.

> I improve SO site as many other developers, almost on daily basis. I think we deserve a good and fast support service.

Well - SE until recently has a *seriously* depleted CM team. While they're ramping up - they were down to 4 + 2 support folks who were pitching in, and currently are slightly over a dozen including CM management folks. Its not *that* many, so patience would probably be appreciated on their end.

As a mod who often has to escalate 'messy' things, I've found that unless its time sensitive, the 'best' way is simply to escalate and wait for the CM team to get around to your ticket.

Especially considering Animuson's comment

> @Sonic As of ~November the support team no longer handles the Public Q&A queue, and it's handled by the community team directly (they forward stuff to us that isn't theirs instead). I haven't touched a community ticket in a while, myself. But I can say they have been very backlogged through much of January and even had a custom "response times may be longer" message going out for a while. –

It either needed no response, or is on a backlog I'd suspect, and probably isn't too helpful to push for a response IMO unless its time sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I flagged in SO again and inserted the only evidence I had which was a link of my error posting. And it was solved. So I think you nailed it with " well try to do better in future" ...

Answer (score 2):

> Why do they take so long to review the ticket?

Can be several reasons, for example the case is complex and requires joint effort of several people, or the team that handles the tickets has lots of tickets in their backlog so new tickets wait until older tickets are resolved, kind of like the queue in shops.

> What can I do about this?

Wait. If you don't get any response after, say, a month, you can look in the profiles of Community Team members, most have their email there, and you can send one a polite email asking about it. Only to one, only once, and keep it polite and to the point. Also, if you don't get any response - better wait than pushing it again.

> Is this normal?

For complex cases yes it is, and when the team has a flood of tickets, which happens from time to time. So overall, yes, having to wait a long time for a response isn't uncommon.

> Are they even going to review it?

Well I can't know for sure but I can tell they'll do their best to review it as soon as possible, in the best way possible.

Comment: "you can look in the profiles of Community Team members" how can you do that?

Comment: @Gass See here: [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what does it do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do)